# Prove that $B = B ^+$ iff $BB \subseteq B$

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

Umm...so what?
I am so lost on this proof.  I know $B^+$ is $BB^*$ or $B^+$ has all the strings that are 1 or more concatenations of strings from $B$.  This is what I managed to logic so far.

> if $B = B^+$, then $BB \subseteq B^+$.

I have no clue where to go from here.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think i get more out of this if i think hard enough here.  BB = B^2, so when n >= 2, B^2 ⊆ B+.

Comment: If $BB\subseteq B$ then $BBB\subseteq BB\subseteq B$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The condition $B^2 \subseteq B$ says that $B$ is closed under ([concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)) product and $B^+$ denotes the [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) generated by $B$. Thus both conditions simply mean that $B$ is a subsemigroup of the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) and hence are equivalent.